# Where is FORTRAN getting these values from?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am an absolute beginner to FORTRAN and am painstakingly converting a 1000 line FORTRAN source file to MATLAB for my own use. I have been going fine so far by putting in heaps of `PRINT` statements to keep track of variables and ensure the maths is working correctly. I have come to a strange happening in FORTRAN which I cannot work out.

There is a subroutine which is defined as so

```
subroutine addprc 
complex tmat,b,ci,c1,c2,cim,ab1(50),ab2(50),acans(10,2),fg1(50),fg2(50)
common dtr,rtd,pi 
common /mtxcom/ nrank,nranki,tmat(50,50),b(50,50),cmxnrm(25)
common /cmvcom/ nm,kmv,cmv,twm,prodm
```

There is a bit more `common` and `dimension` allocations below but they shouldn't be relevant. The very first time the `ab1(50)` array is defined is in this subroutine. For my MATLAB script I have initialized it as `ab1=zeros(1,50);`. It is then used in this loop (in FORTRAN):

```
do 20 n = 1,nrank 
np = n+nrank 
cn = real(n)
n1 = n+1 
c1 = 4.0*ci**n 
c2 = 4.0*ci**n1 
p1 = cn*costh*pnmllg(n1)-(cn+cmv)*pnmllg(n) 
p2 = cmv*pnmllg(n1) 
ab1(n-ij) = c1*p2*uu1 
ab1(np-ijt) = -c2*p1*uu1 
ab2(n-ij) = -c1*p1*uu2 
ab2(np-ijt) = c2*p2*uu2
```

I have checked the values of all the other variables at this point and they agree with my MATLAB script. Working backwards I have discovred the problem that somehow the `ab1` already contains values. A print command just before the loop e.g.

```
PRINT *,'before ab1', SUM(ab1)
do 20 n = 1,1
```

returns `(107.500008, 5.38305187)`. It is a complex number so the two values are fine, but whats not fine is the fact it has anything in it at all? Infact the only time `ab1` is used at all is in this block of code.

Is there anything I am missing here? I looked in the source file (ctrl-f: ab1) to find any instances of it. The original source is a .for file, and I have compiled them under Eclipse using gfortran. Thanks for your time.

Comment: re: common blocks being irrelevant, be aware, if the symbol is an a common block, some other program unit may well access that common block with different symbol names.

Comment: Where is the `ij` `ijt` loop?

Comment: @george: I did notice this behavior from other variables. The only thing I am not sure is how to know what is using it since this is the first time `ab1` is defined. @ja72 The `ij` `ijt` loop is defined a little earlier as follows. `ij = kmv-1, if(ij.lt.0), ij = 0 ijt = 2*ij` so nothing too fancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wondering: what you would expect there instead?

These values come from memory. When you call something (function/program/subroutine) that defines a variable some piece of memory is associated with defined variable, but until you assign something to the variable it will use whatever was present in memory before. As computer memory is constantly being reused without being reset you may get there value from a variable from the other called function/subroutine that already ended, a piece of memory from other process (with the exception of some pages that must be emptied by kernel as they may contain private data) or anything else. The general rule is that nobody will do such an expensive operation as setting memory to some value unless he deadly needs this (e.g. like here where you do set memory associated with variables to numbers you need or when not erasing memory is a potential security flaw).

As a summary: these values come from uninitialized memory. Exact contents is undefined.

You do not get errors at accessing uninitialized memory because checking whether memory is initialized is a very expensive operation. But there are tools that will show you errors in this case:

1. If you want to know whether your program accesses uninitialized memory you may run it under `valgrind`. Note that such checks are very expensive: under valgrind you easily get your program running worse then an order of magnitude slower.
2. There is also clang [MemorySanitizer](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/MemorySanitizer.html) filter that claims to do this job with only 3x slowdown, but you will need to translate fortran program to C (e.g. with f2c) before using clang as it is C/C++ compiler. You also need to compile all libraries your program uses with clang with this filter enabled.

Comment: Fortran compilers (the ones I'm familiar with) can identify the use of uninitialised variables, `valgrind` is scarcely necessary for such a simple task.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Here: maybe. In general: no. Consider the case when you call a subroutine defined in the other file supplying it with an uninitialized variable and compile these files separately. Compiler instance that compiles caller does not know whether you meant to path a value or it is usual for low-level languages returned-value-in-argument situation. Compiler instance that compiles callee does not know whether subroutine will be passed initialized or uninitialized memory. Linker simply does not care and has no means of detecting such situation. Thus you will have to use valgrind.

Comment: Hi ZyX. I do have a bit of background in C++ so the fact that it could be reading memory values crossed my mind. However, I have just turned my computer on this morning and run the program again, and `ab1 (107.500008,5.38305187 )`. So it is equaling the very same thing as it did on a previous session. I think this would be very unlikely with garbage values. Note this is FORTRAN 77 standard if that helps anything. I will have a try with valgrind though...

Comment: Hmm, I think you  may be right ZyX. I went to the very start of the prorgram where a variable is defined as `complex aa(50,50)` and it also has some values in it. Strangely enough, simply adding the statement `PRINT *,'aa is', aa` changed the value of `SUM(ab1)`. So I guess the program will only ever write values to the first n values of ab1 and then use them later. Anything wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: I have tracked the problem back further and I can see you are right. For some reason I thought FORTRAN initialized all variables as 0 like MATLAB did...

Comment: @SteveHatcher - That practice can lead to some hard-to-track errors.

Comment: @Idigas Only assuming valgrind or such is available. If it is not I do not see how initializing variables to zero will make such errors harder to track then initializing variables to “random” value (which may be zero just as well as the value variable should have been initialized to).

Answer (score 2):

`ab1` is small array (50 * 8 = 400 bytes) and is therefore most likely allocated on the program stack. The stack is used to store local variables as well as the return address of the caller whenever a subroutine is called. Initially the stack pages contain all zeros but as subroutines get called it grows and is populated with some numbers. Later when the subroutine returns the stack pointer is changed but the values remain on the stack and are later overwritten by the new calls. When `ab1` is allocated, its memory would initially be populated with old stack values that come from previously called subroutines. Most FORTRAN compilers do not generate by default instructions to initialise stack variables as it could be an expensive operation.

If your program is completely deterministic, i.e. there are no subroutine calls that depend on the value of some (pseudo-)random numbers or the initial PRNG seed is always the same, then sans the return addresses all other content of the stack is going to be the same between many executions of your program, e.g. one in the evening and one in the morning.

That's why `SUM(ab1)` always returns `(107.500008, 5.38305187)`. And it is actually a GoodThing(tm) - it shows that your computer is a deterministic device, i.e. it reproduces the output given the same algorithm and the same input and therefore could be used to execute programming tasks. This is also a BadThing(tm) since predictable stack values lie in the base of many attacks on the OS security, but that lies way outside the scope of your problem.